# MySQL Regexp on blob column

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

I am having problem with using MySQL's REGEXP operator with blob column.

Clause:

```
WHERE table.blobColumn REGEXP '"postalCode";s:[1-9]'
```

won't return me single result, even I got thousands of records that got 'postal' inside their blob column value. Is there any way I can do REGEXP on this column types in MySQL?

Comment: Why are you using `REGEXP 'postal'` your not even using a complex regex match pattern you can replace it with `LIKE %postal%`

Comment: Actually this is my regular expression: "postalCode";s:[1-9].

Comment: Give some example data and explain what you are trying to match..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've got serialized php object stored into blob column of my table. Here's fragment of data from that column: >> s:10:"postalCode";s:5:"55076";s:1 <<. What I want is to check if postalCode has >= 1 field length.

Comment: A regex looking like `"postalCode";s:[1-9]+;"[1-9]+` might do the trick.

Comment: This won't work for multibyte character sets. Are you using the same quotes? You might want to ignore the quotes: `postalCode.;s:[1-9]`

Comment: @itsLex Before I try anything, I would just note that: `WHERE table.blobColumn REGEXP "postal"` returns me 0 results.

Comment: With single quotes I hope?

Comment: @itsLex Yes, still nothing returned.

Answer (score 0):

Using a REGEXP on a blob field does not work well because of the ASCII NUL value ('\0').
One way to make it work is to replace the NUL value before doing the REGEXP evaluation, as following:

```
... WHERE replace(table.blobColumn, '\0', '') REGEXP '"postalCode";s:[1-9]'
```